# Log record is not propagated to the root handler

Tags: python, logging

I noticed very strange behaviour with logging and logger:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logger.warning("A") # Print one message
logging.warning("A") # Pirnts another message
logger.warning("A") # Prints two messages ??
```

Why `logger.warning` prints one message at first and two messages later?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `logger` inherits from the root logger. That means log message is first print with the `logger` and then propagated to the root.

But root logger has no associated handlers at start - it's done with [basicConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) which adds `StreamHandler` and default formatter when called without parameters. And if you look into module-level `warning` function of `logging` you notice:

```
def warning(msg, *args, **kwargs):
    if len(root.handlers) == 0:
        basicConfig()
    root.info(msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

So that extra handler is set after `logging.warning` and that's why second `logger.warning` call logs two messages.